# Unity switching weapons on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

So, I have the following code for switching weapons inside a placeholder and I want to extend it, to switching weapons from a button too, so I will be able to switch them on my mobile too.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WeaponSwitcher : MonoBehaviour {
    public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) 
        {
            if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            else
                selectedWeapon++;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) 
        {
            if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            else
                selectedWeapon--;
        }

        if (previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon) 
        {
            SelectWeapon ();
        }

    }

    void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform) 
        {
            if (i == selectedWeapon)
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            else
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do? I'm newbie and everything I have tried didn't work :/

I have tried with an independent script just for the button to looking for which weapon is active and deactivate the other (there just two) etc but it didn't work.

```
public class ChangeWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public GameObject gun; 
    public GameObject shotgun; 

    void switchWeapons () 
    { 
        gun = GameObject.Find("Gun"); 
        shotgun = GameObject.Find("Shotgun"); 

        if (gun.gameObject.activeSelf) 
        { 
            shotgun.gameObject.SetActive (true); 
            gun.gameObject.SetActive (false); 
        }
        else
        {
            shotgun.gameObject.SetActive (false); 
            gun.gameObject.SetActive (true); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us everything you have tried so we can better help you.

Comment: I have tried with a independent script just for the button to looking for which weapon is active and deactivate the other (there just two) etc but didn't worked.
`public class ChangeWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject gun;
 public GameObject shotgun;

 void switchWeapons () {
  gun = GameObject.Find("Gun");
  shotgun = GameObject.Find("Shotgun");

  if (gun.gameObject.activeSelf) {
   shotgun.gameObject.SetActive (true);
   gun.gameObject.SetActive (false);
  }
  else{
   shotgun.gameObject.SetActive (false);
   gun.gameObject.SetActive (true);
  }

 }
}
`

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, it's unreadable and not all comments may be shown initially. [Edit] your question instead. While editing, please also clarify what you mean by "didn't work". What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors or exceptions? You may want to read [ask].

Comment: *`looking for which weapon is active and deactivate the other (there just two) etc but it didn't work.`* Define didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really simple solution that works.

I placed two buttons on top of another, I disabled the second one and on click actions I do the followings:

1. Enable the second button
2. Disable the first button
3. Disable the first gun
4. Enable the second gun

And vise versa.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZbUu.jpg)